# Mapping Settings pages to Keys

Tags: android

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));
```

Above code is used to call a setting through Intent

i need to map that intent in Combination of key..

for example

i need to call settings intent by pressing  a+s+d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within one of your own activities, override methods like `onKeyDown()`, examine the `KeyEvent` to see if it matches, and start the activity if it does.

If you are trying to do this on a global basis, that is not possible from the Android SDK.

Comment: The above code reads only BackKey,HomeKey,VolumeUpkey etc it will reads keyboard keys

Comment: @Bucks: `onKeyDown()` and `onKeyUp()` of the activity will receive all key events that are not handled by the widget with focus. You may therefore need to add yet more smarts to your app to handle key events via subclasses or listeners on focusable widgets.